# How to obtain a rectangle's side's positions if its origin isn't in its middle?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Basically I have an algorithm which generates rooms and corridors randomly and each time a room is made, a new corridor is placed on $1/4$ of the room's sides and its origin point is set to that room's random side

But now I'm trying to make a collision algorithm, but I can't work out the corridor's side positions for it, because each of their origin points differ from one another.  I can't set their origin points to their middle, because that would make them off-centered.

EDIT: https://github.com/MrCappucino/Dungeon This is all the source code with some pictures of the map.

[image]

EDIT 2: Even better explanation (I hope)

[image: Possible starting (origin) points]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Math.SE!  Your question is very unclear at the moment.  Consider updating it (maybe with some pictures and sample code) and you're more likely to get answers.

Comment: I've updated it. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: I've added the picture from your link.  It's better to include pictures, source code etc. directly rather than linking to them as links might not always be active.

Comment: Try and define more carefully what you mean by: collision, origin, origin point, side position.  It's still not clear.

Comment: I've made another graphic, hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Comment: What information are you allowed to use, and what form do you want the output in?  Perhaps a 'black box' example would help: give us some sample input and tell us what output you expect to receive.

Comment: I thought the question was sufficiently clear, and there appears to be a good answer (actually, one very simple answer specific to this exact problem and a more general answer that can also apply). I'm not sure what additional detail is desired; perhaps a statement that the widths of all corridors are equal and "starting points" are at the midpoints of each end of the corridor. It also appears that every edge of every corridor is parallel to either the $x$ or $y$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that the corridor is a rectangle;
that you know two points on the corridor,
one at each end (indicated by the colored dots in your figures),
that each of the known points is at the midpoint of a side of the rectangle;
that the width of every corridor (that is, the length of the sides
on which the known points lie) is the same;
that the distance between the known points of every corridor is
no less than some known minimum value;
that the corridors are drawn in a coordinate system with $x$ and $y$ axes;
and that the sides each corridor are parallel with 
one or the other of these axes.

For convenience, set $\delta$ to half the width of a corridor.
That is, each corridor is $2\delta$ units wide.
Also, consider the corridor to be aligned with the line through its
two known points and with the coordinate axis parallel to that line.

Let the coordinates of the two known points at the corridor's ends
by $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.

There are two cases to consider: a corridor aligned with the $x$ axis
and a corridor aligned with the $y$ axis.
There are a few ways to tell which case is which, all by comparing the
coordinates of the known points:

- Determine whether $y_1 = y_2$. This is safe even against the usual floating-point errors of computer programs as long as the coordinates of one endpoint of the corridor are gotten by copying the other endpoint and then modifying just one coordinate.
- Determine whether $|y_1 - y_2| < \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is greater than the largest possible discrepancy that your floating point arithmetic might cause in the coordinate values, but smaller than the length of the shortest possible corridor.
- Determine whether $|y_1 - y_2| < |x_1 - x_2|$. This works as long as the minimum corridor length is greater than the largest possible floating-point error you might encounter.

The two cases are:

**Case 1:** Depending on which of the three tests you use, this case occurs if $y_1 = y_2$, or $|y_1 - y_2| < \epsilon$, or $|y_1 - y_2| < |x_1 - x_2|$.
This corridor is aligned with the $x$-axis.
The coordinates of the corners of the corridor are then
(in consecutive sequence around the perimeter)

$$\begin{array}{c}
(x_1,y_1-\delta),\\ (x_1,y_1+\delta),\\ (x_2,y_2+\delta),\\ (x_2,y_2-\delta).
\end{array}$$

**Case 2:** Depending on which of the three tests you use, this case occurs if $x_1 = x_2$, or $|x_1 - x_2| < \epsilon$, or $|x_1 - x_2| < |y_1 - y_2|$.
This corridor is aligned with the $y$-axis.
The coordinates of the corners of the corridor are then

$$\begin{array}{c}
(x_1+\delta,y_1),\\ (x_1-\delta,y_1),\\ (x_2-\delta,y_2),\\ (x_2+\delta,y_2).
\end{array}$$

If you encounter the "third case", where neither of the conditions you
tested for Case 1 or Case 2 is true, then you invoke some kind of
error reporting and debug your program, because at least one of its
assumptions has been violated.